# How To Handle Pagination And Ordering In Cypher Query?

Tags: sorting, neo4j, pagination, cypher, union

I am writing a cypher query in neo4j that merge few seperate queries with'UNION' operator. Now, the final result need to be sorted according to a specific column and I also need to be able to use 'LIMIT' to the final result so that I can fetch based on pagination request.

How to achieve that? adding 'ORDER BY' or 'LIMIT' at the end doesn't seems to work. Can't find a way to wrap the result as temporary set(as in sql queries) either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to add a `ORDER BY` or `SKIP/LIMIT` clause to the global set of UNION.

This is a pending feature request, see https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2725

Maybe you can share your query and we can find a way to do it without UNION ?